# Dependency Injection in Silex controllers

Tags: php, frameworks, silex

I need some help with Silex controllers.
Here is my code:

```
$app->get('/','AppComponents\Controllers\HelloController::index' );
```

All i want is that my controller class had access to Silex\Apllication object.

I wanted to inject it in constructor like this:

```
class HelloController{

protected $app; 

function __construct(Application $app) {
    $this->app = $app;
}
```

But this code fails.. On the contrary if i inject Application in my method of my controller like this

```
 function index(Silex\Application $app) {
    return  new Response("hello");
}
```

It works.

Is there any way to inject Application object directly in my constructor function?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the controllers as services. This is explained [in the documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html).